# Help proving a statement in calculus

Tags: calculus

So let $x>-1$

And I want to prove that if $t\leq 0$ or $t\geq1$ it indicates that  $$(1+x)^t \geq 1+tx$$

So I have noticed that both sides are always greater than 0.

But I wonder whether this can be proven using some mean value or intermediate vakue theorems(rolle and lagrange)

But i dont notice the function to use in it, any help woudl be appreciated.

Comment: Right side isn't greater than zero if $t=-2$ and $x=1$...

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: But I suggest you to use induction

Comment: How can he use induction?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar $t$ is real, so induction would be non-trivial.

Comment: @Sisyphus More than non-trivial: practically impossible, as one needs a well-ordered set, if not the natural numbers, to work out induction...

Answer (score 1):

For $t\geq 1$ and $x\geq 0$ define $$f(x):= (1+x)^t-1-tx$$

Then $$f'(x)= t(1+x)^{t-1}-t = t((1+x)^{t-1}-1)\geq 0$$ so $f$ is nondecreasing and since $f(0)=0$ we have $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, i got that part, what about for $t\leq 0$?